# Why is Webots running so slow on my computer?

Tags: simulation, simulator, webots

The provided sample simulations are running very slowly in Webots. How can I improve this?

I am using Webots R2022b on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if your graphics driver are installed correctly and up-to-date?

You can find some instructions to verify the graphics driver installation for Webots [here](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/verifying-your-graphics-driver-installation).
Note that it is recommended to run Webots on computers equipped with recent NVIDIA or AMD graphics cards.

You might also try other tweaks to speed up your machine:

- on laptop computer you should check the power options and make sure to use the high performance power plan
- disable the Ubuntu desktop animations (from the "Accessibility" section in the Settings app)  that could use ample system resources, especially on older computers, and cause a huge performance drop of the rendering system.settings

Comment: If running Webots inside a virtual machine, I would recommend [VMware Workstation Player](https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation-player.html) over [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) as it provides a significantly better OpenGL hardware acceleration when enabled. Also, when running Webots in a Docker, you should ensure you are using the [official Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/r/cyberbotics/webots), or derive your custom Docker image from the [NVIDIA opengl](https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/opengl) image and obviously run it on a machine equipped with a NVIDIA card.